# Can you run Windows batch file not in a command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My programming teacher is requiring that everyone participate in the science fair this year, and now they accept computer-related projects. So, knowing only one language (Windows batch), I asked if I could make some kind of text based game in batch code. She said that I can only write the code, but not execute it.

She said that if we're even caught on the command prompt, we apparently get in big trouble and never get access to a school computer for the rest of the time I'm at the high school, or something like that... Even if all the code contains is a bunch of echos and simple variables, she won't let me and my partner run it. She also said that we must work on the project during school in her class.

So to sum all that up, she's letting me write a game/program, but I'm not allowed to test it to make sure it works in school, which will be when I'm writing it most...

**So is there any way to run/test a batch script with simple echo and set /p commands without the *"dangerous, black command prompt"* showing up?**

I think she has no idea what she's talking about, because on the board, she wrote "back script" lol

Comment: @ergonaut - that will only prevent the code that is running not be displayed in the command prompt as it's running. A command prompt will _always_ open when you run batch, no exceptions. You can think of batch scripts as a list of command prompt commands, and the order in which to run them.

Comment: Just my opinion but  I think you are being shortchanged educationally by incompetent teachers. Teaching programming and forbidding the command prompt is like teaching driving and forbidding you even get in a car.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your programming teacher expects you to program in the language that she's teaching.

Comment: She's not teaching any languages at this point. Only Alice 3. She said we might learn Python near the end of the year though.

Comment: I use @echo off all the time, but she doesn't care. To her, black box=bad. Always

Comment: @LynnCrumbling But the point is to see the text on the screen and type in your responses.

Comment: I completely agree with @paisanco, writing code but having no way of testing it is insane. While i see why your teacher wishes to limit your use of command prompt because of the control it has over the computer, there are better ways than banning batch scripts all together. As an alternative to the "*dangerous black command window*", you could change the `color` and `title` of the window, or you could work on the code at school, copy the files to an external drive, and test them at home. Best of luck.

Comment: Batch isn't really adequate for your purposes anyway.  I expect you'd be able to pick up a better language quickly enough - except that many of the languages suitable for beginners also involve the dreaded "black box".  I don't know what sort of game you were thinking of, but perhaps [Smash and the Rex interpreter](http://www.rinkworks.com/smash/) would be appropriate?  ... of course that involves running a third-party program, but it doesn't use the "black box".

Comment: If you can only use stuff built into Windows, perhaps vbscript.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: a VBScript, JScript or PowerShell program _also_ requires the cmd.exe window in order to run...

Comment: @Aacini: no, if you double-click a .vbs file it runs in GUI mode.  You can use, e.g., MsgBox to interact with the user.  (Of course, vbscript is just as capable and as dangerous as the command window, but so long as the OP gets permission...)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: you are right, but in such a case the project would be presented the next year, when the OP learned enough VBS in order to do that... **`;-)`**

Comment: @Aacini: I think you underestimate the learning speed of a motivated teenager. :-)  But I agree that VBS wouldn't be my *first* choice.

Comment: The other potential advantage of Smash/Rex would be that a sizable chunk of the work would be the design/writing of the game, so even if you did have to do all your debugging at home you would still have plenty of work to do while at school.

Comment: Perhaps powershell is the answer... ah, that beautiful, blue, *peaceful*, not-at-all-dangerous window. :)

Answer (score 0):

A batch file runs like any other executable file by double-clicking the file within Windows. However, because a batch file runs in a command line it immediately exits when done, so you may only see a black box for a second.

If the batch file is closing too fast, or you want to read the output from the batch file you can edit the batch file and add a pause to the end of the file. The pause command waits for user input before continuing.

A `.BAT` file can be made into a `.EXE` or `.COM` file to keep the program's source hidden from a user. You could use the [.BAT to .EXE converter](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) file to convert the batch files to `.EXE` file. In this program you can point to the batch file you want to convert into an executable file, include additional files, change the icon of the file, and add file details.

For Information on Batch files, this is one of the best [resource](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm).

Comment: I know how to code in batch and everything, my only issue is running it without the black box, are popups with a text input a viable option?

Comment: @TrivisionZero: no.  Batch = command window (aka "black box").  It can't be avoided.

Comment: @TrivisionZero in the answer that i have posted you will see the black box only for a fraction of a second. It is a system event. you can't avoid it

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC: since the batch file in question is going to have to accept input and produce output, the command window will have to remain on screen for the entire time.  The OP isn't talking about something that can just do its work quickly and exit, he wants to build a game.

Comment: You could use vbscript to create a hidden process that executes your batch script.  But then what sort of user interface would your game have?  Here's an idea.  They don't want you launching a console window on a school computer, right?  Could you bring your own laptop and develop on that?

Comment: If not, then I suggest you start teaching yourself a little JavaScript.  There are more tutorials online than you could ever want, it's easy to learn, it requires no 3rd party software installation, it's dead useful, and it can even improve your batch scripting through batch + Jscript hybrids eventually.

Comment: @rojo Sadly, I do not have a laptop, nor does my partner, so either I purely write the code at school, or learn JavaScript... Isn't that a web language? Are you suggesting I make an online text based game with it? hmm... That might work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
color F0
mode con lines=25 cols=60
cls
title "Notepad - MyProgram.bat"

set /P "name=What is your name? "
echo Hello %name%, glad to see you...
pause
```

Execute it via a double click or enter in files browser...

Comment: Dangerous, in my opinion.  The teacher *might* not recognize that the white box is the same thing as the dreaded black box, but if she does the OP could get into trouble.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: She agreed that the OP _write_ the program, so it is only necessary to give the cmd.exe window the same appearance than the window used to create the program...

Comment: Yes, but this depends on tricking the teacher into thinking that the command window is notepad.  That's the sort of thing that disciplinary committees are liable to overreact to.  (And it doesn't look exactly the same; the system menu icon is a dead giveaway.)